# ajax call throwing not working due to long-script running error in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax call, and it is throwing "not responding due to a long-script is running" in browser and gives a button to stop script.

the url is coming perfectly and the console.log(4) inside the success function is not even loading, it just hangs.

The issue is happening for certain scenarios only for others it is working. I have even compared the data, there is no change in data structure also.

Please helpme out

```
$.ajax({
       timeout: 3000,
       type: "POST",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(apiInput),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(4);
        if (onsuccess !== null) {
            onsuccess(data);
        }
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        if (onerror !== null) {
            onerror(x, y, z);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the onsuccess method do? It is hard for anyone to answer the question without it. What if it contains an infinite loop?

Comment: It will just validate the data and convert it into Base64String and stores in DB. for most of the input it is working fine, but not for few random inputs. so i cant able to figure out the real problem behind this.

Comment: That error message generally means you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code.

Comment: i check my code, it not having any infinte loops. but the strange thing it, the same errored input also works fine. it throws the error randomly. is there anything i need to change syntax wise ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the onsucces part of your Ajax success method is trying to do here.

Try this and look a the console for the errors

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: serviceURL,
    data: JSON.stringify(apiInput),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        if (x.status == 0) {
            console.log('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        } else if (x.status == 404) {
            console.log('Requested URL not found.');
        } else if (x.status == 500) {
            console.log('Internel Server Error.');
        } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
            console.log('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
        } else if (e == 'timeout') {
            console.log('Request Time out.');
        } else {
            console.log('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
        }
    }   
});
```

I think you were trying to check if the API call was successful or not, the way Ajax works is on the status of the request essentially if the request returns a status of 200 (which means it's ok) then it will hit the success part of the method, if it's an error foe example 404 (cannot find the URL) or 500 (internal server error) then the error part of the function will be hit, then just console.log that data and view it as you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the apiInput will have a svg component of a chart and i am to convert it to a Base64String (image) so i can print it on a excel. I tried with you code, it is not even coming inside any of the console.log() in the code.

Comment: @Mani079 So nothing is being out put on the console at all, not even an error message? Remove the dataType attibute on there, because is your are expecting a string, that datatype states you are expecting a json object. Also just to check are you sure about the content type. I would reccomend trying this API in postman tools [link](https://www.getpostman.com/) and make sure you request is working correctly.

Comment: i tried it works. my ajax call also works for all other input, it behaves like this randomly and i couldnt able to figure out the pattern.

Comment: No problem glad i could help, if there is more support you need feel free comment here and i can update my answer further

Comment: thank you very much. after trying with post man i came to know that the JSON object which i was getting from global object has a data property __ob__ . This was the culprit. i removed it by stringifying the JSON object and then parsing that. It solved the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome glad you got to the bottom of your problem